# Sending to multiple e-mail adresses

Tags: c#, email

I can't figure the following out. How do I send an e-mail to multiple e-mail addresses with the following code?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage()
{
    From = fromAddress,
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@example.com", "Name"));
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient2@example.com", "Name"));
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: There is no constructor for `MailMessage` that takes a single instance of a `MailAddress` as a parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use the constructor for `MailMessage` that takes no parameters, then assign the `From` property. The `To` property is actually a collection that lets you add as many people as you would like:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to1@example.com", "To One"));
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to2@example.com", "To Two"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the protery `To` of any `MailMessage` object:

```
 message.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@def.com","ABC"));
```